# Best tutorial for learning Wordpress plugin development?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to wordpress. Can any one suggest me a best tutorial for learning wordpress plugin development and some simple examples? I've done some searches in google and got some informations.

Comment: Do you want to program the core, plugins, or just install and use it?

Comment: I want to start learning the plugin development in Wordpress.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Developer_Documentation) is possibly the place you'll spend most of your time while you're writing WP plugins - at least, I spend most of my time there (mostly for the [function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference))

Nettuts just did a [plugin introduction article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/your-first-wordpress-plugin-simple-optimization/) which is well explained as well.